# Hello Word javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou acompanhado o tutorial do firefox porém não estou conseguindo executar um hello word. Segue o código.

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript 01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Código JavaScript

```
alert('123');
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';
```

O `alert` funciona, ta chegando lá. Queria saber porque não alterou o texto de `h1` para Hello Word.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque seu `Javascript` está no `head`, ou seja, está sendo executado antes que o `h1` esteja no `DOM`.

**Opção 1 - Carregar no final do body:**

Altere para o seguinte:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript 01</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Teste</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Opção 2 - Utilizar o evento onload:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript 01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="executar()">
    <h1>Teste</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function executar() {
  alert('123');
  var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
  myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';
}
```

Comment: Mas, este é o padrão html 5 ? Não existe outro método ?

Comment: @AbnerPassosMagalhaes na realidade você nunca vai alterar um elemento do `DOM` logo ao iniciar o seu `script`, concorda? Senão você tem que colocar no evento `onload` da página.

Comment: valeu!! Funcionou.

Comment: verdade. Valeu man!

Comment: @AbnerPassosMagalhaes A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção é colocar o código no `onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
    myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';
}
```